# No children are rendered when the user navigates to a specific route in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been playing with react router and trying different things and I just ran into this issue.

When user routes to simple `localhost:3000`, the expected routing happens and I see the `ParamsComponent` but when user navigates to `localhost:3000/netflix` which is there is one of the link, I don't see the child component to be rendering on the screen.

Here is my Router config:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={ParamsComponent} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={Child} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is my `ParamsComponent` component:

```
class ParamsComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <h2>Accounts</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ParamsComponent;
```

And here is my `Child` component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log("child", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: I don't see a problem. Could you please create a sandbox for it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0mjo5kxy7l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only have one top level `Router` so that every `Link` component gets the same `history` object through context as your `Route` components.

Remove `Router` from `ParamsComponent` and it will work.

```
class ParamsComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Accounts</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```